# How to replace all the \ which is coming inside the string which also contains a string

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am calling REST api through ADF and storing the data in blob storage. There are few columns which has value like `\\name\\":\\"what we do\\",\\"values\\":[\\"food\\"]"`

The output should be `name:what we do,values:food`
How to handle such column values using dataflow visual builder expression before writing into a final csv file.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need a [regexReplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#regexreplace) in a derive Column block.

The expression used is `regexReplace(body, '\\[|\\]|\\\\|\"', '')`

the regex separate following 4 cases by `\`, which means `or`

- `\\[` : replace open square bracket
- `\\]` : replace close square bracket
- `\\\\` : replace double slash
- `\"` : replace double quote

output in ADF:
[image]